# Perl or Java Sentiment Analysis

Tags: java, perl, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I was wondering if anybody knew of any good Perl modules and/or Java classes for sentiment analysis.  I have read about LingPipe, but the program would eventually need to be used for commercial use so something open-source would be better.  I also looked into GATE, but their documentation on sentiment analysis is sparse at best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [Rate_Sentiment](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Rate_Sentiment) in the [WebService::GoogleHack](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WebService-GoogleHack/) module at [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/). There's more information about the project at [SourceForge](http://google-hack.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I saw this, but it doesn't have any ratings and I was worried about scalability since it mentions using the Google API.  Do you have any experience with it yourself?

Comment: No, I've never used it. However, [Ted Pedersen](http://www.d.umn.edu/~tpederse/) seems to be one of the authors. He's a [pretty major figure](http://search.cpan.org/~tpederse/) in Perl NLP.

Answer (score 3):

I just added a sentiment analysis library to my Social Media Analytics Research Toolkit. The blog post / announcement is ***[here](http://borasky-research.net/2011/01/24/the-social-media-analytics-research-toolkit-now-with-sentiment-analysis/)***. It's in R, not in Java, but there's a good interface between R and Java in the toolkit, so you can write your "glue code" in Java to call the R library. There's also an R - Python interface in the toolkit.

There's supposed to be an R / Perl interface too, but I haven't been able to contact the maintainer about bugs, so I took it out of the build.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at LingPipe (Java) based sentiment analysis  at:

http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/sentiment/read-me.html

and GATE (http://gate.ac.uk/sentiment/)

For more generalized NLP parsers see The Stanford parser (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml), NLTK (Python) (http://www.nltk.org/), etc.

I'm not aware of any similar open source tools for Perl, although there are some good basic references out there to get you started, e.g.:

Billisoly, R. (2008) Practical Text Mining with Perl. Wiley. ISBN 978-0-470-17643-6.